Short story in the form of a search history of a man stranded on a planet
I'm pretty sure it was nominated for a Hugo or Nebula. It could have been a short story or a novelette, but definitely not a novella.
I probably read this between 2009 and 2014.
It is meant to look like a log of a computer answering someone's searches and questions. And through this, it's revealed the person asking the question is a man or astronaut trapped on a (desert?) planet somewhere in a vehicle of some kind, and is slowly running out of oxygen.

In roughly which year did you read this?

Could this be the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/286896/short-story-about-men-stranded-on-mars-who-are-running-out-of-air-each-takes-a/286913#286913 ?

@Dosco -- it's not that one because, as I recall, there was only one person in the spacecraft. And the story is told entirely from the perspective of the AI/search engine

@LogicDictates - It would probably be between 2009-2014

This sounds likely to be Mars: A Traveler's Guide by Ruth Nestvold, published in the January 2008 issue of The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction, and nominated for a Nebula award for best short story of 2009.  The synopsis posted here seems to match the general theme:

Ruth Nestvold, whose story “Mars: A Traveler’s Guide” appears in the January 2008 issue of F&SF, said in an interview that the story is about a tourist on Mars who is stranded alone after an accident caused by a major dust storm. "The tour guide [is] dead and the rover damaged," Nestvold said. "The only thing the tourist has that is working is the supposedly ‘intelligent’ computer system to try to help him or her figure out a way to survive."


This story is told entirely through the Mars rover computer system’s responses to the protagonist’s queries.

Edit: Thanks to the user in the comments below for providing an Internet Archive link to the story in question!
The story begins with the unfortunate tourist making fairly technical queries about their situation:

I'm sorry, I have no entry in my database for "rover accident."
Would you like to select a new topic?
You have chosen the topic “pressurized rover”:
The pressurized rover is especially designed to withstand the stresses
of the Martian environment. The passenger compartment is protected by
a waffled body tub in order to ensure that the cabin will not lose
pressure in case the outer shell is damaged. Radiator fins help
control the interior temperature. The rover has two independent
hydrogen fuel cell systems, one on each side, and a power transmission
grid wired directly into each wheel — a design very resistant to
breakdowns —

Unfortunately, the computers responses, while technically accurate, are not particularly useful in actually resolving the situation they find themselves in as any solutions would require the tour guide to be alive, or access to equipment that was destroyed in the incident. The traveler becomes increasingly frantic and irate:

I have no entry in my database for "tour guide dead."
Would you like to select a new topic?
You have chosen the topic "Emergency":
In the case of an emergency situation, your tour guide —
I have no entry in my database for "fuck you."
Would you like to select a new topic?


You have chosen the topic "Notify Mars Emergency Authority":
In order to notify the Mars Emergency Authority (MEA), use either the
communications module in your pressure suit or the communications
system of the rover. Give your location, the unit number of your tour,
and a precise description of the problem. A rescue team will be to
your site within eight hours.
I have no entry in my database for "rescue my ass."
Would you like to select a new topic?
I'm sorry, the volume of your last request was too high for me to understand. Please repeat.
You have chosen the topic "help":
The Help System of the Mars Traveler's Guide is an extensive database
covering a wide range of topics, both informational and practical. If
you do not find the topic you need, contact user support and make a
suggestion. We are always happy to receive feedback.

The story then ends on a final chilling note from the computer:

You have not made a selection for more than ten minutes. In order to access the database, select a topic on your wrist unit or voice a
topic of your own. If there is no appropriate entry in the database,
search for a similar word or term. If you are no longer in need of the
help system, select or voice "quit."
Would you like to select a new topic?
The system has been idle for more than thirty minutes and will go into sleep mode. To reactivate the system, simply voice your request.
The system has been idle for more than sixty minutes. This system is shutting down.


A scan of that issue is available at the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v114n01_2008-01/page/n96/mode/2up

The ISFDB entry for that story indicates that it was nominated for a Nebula: https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?835173

Oop, I forgot to mention the Nebula nomination, which is obviously how I found it. XD  Thank you, I'll edit that in.

This is definitely it! Thank you.
